# index dup key on field that is NOT an index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this user schema:

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose"), 
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:
    {type: String,
    unique: true
    },
    password: String,
    privileges:
    [{
            region: Number,
            read: Number,
            write: Number,
            edit: Number
    }]
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

with this html

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
{
    window.x = document.querySelector(".set-nou-privilegii");
    x.addEventListener("click", adaugarePrivilegii); 
});

var y = 1;
var x = document.querySelector(".set-nou-privilegii");
function adaugarePrivilegii(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    x.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin",
    `<br/>
    <label for="region">Regiune:</label>
    <input type="Number" name="privileges[${y}][region]" id="region-inregistrare" placeholder="cod regiune"><br/>
    <label for="citire">Citire (0 - nu, 1 - da):</label>
    <input type="Number" name="privileges[${y}][read]" id="citire-inregistrare" placeholder="1-acces, 0-nu"><br/>
    <label for="scriere">Scriere (0 - nu, 1 - da):</label>
    <input type="Number" name="privileges[${y}][write]" id="scriere-inregistrare" placeholder="1-acces, 0-nu"><br/>
    <label for="editare">Editare (0 - nu, 1 - da):</label>
    <input type="Number" name="privileges[${y}][edit]" id="editare-inregistrare" placeholder="1-acces, 0-nu"><br/>`)
    y++;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <script src="/javascript/js-inregistrare.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title>Inregistrari</title>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="center">
    <img src="/img/logo.jpg" class="logo-inregistrare">
    <form action="/register" method="POST" class="form-inregistrare">
        <label for="username">Nume utilizator:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username-inregistrare" placeholder="nume utilizator"><br/>
        <label for="password">Parola:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password-inregistrare" placeholder="parola"><br/>
        <label for="region">Regiune:</label>
        <input type="Number" name="privileges[0][region]" id="region-inregistrare" placeholder="cod regiune"><br/>
        <label for="citire">Citire (0 - nu, 1 - da):</label>
        <input type="Number" name="privileges[0][read]" id="citire-inregistrare" placeholder="1-acces, 0-nu"><br/>
        <label for="scriere">Scriere (0 - nu, 1 - da):</label>
        <input type="Number" name="privileges[0][write]" id="scriere-inregistrare" placeholder="1-acces, 0-nu"><br/>
        <label for="editare">Editare (0 - nu, 1 - da):</label>
        <input type="Number" name="privileges[0][edit]" id="editare-inregistrare" placeholder="1-acces, 0-nu"><br/>
        <button class="set-nou-privilegii">Adaugare set nou privilegii</button><br/>
        <button class="trimite-inregistrare">Trimite</button><br/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and these routes

```js
var express = require("express"),
    router  = express.Router(),
    User = require("../models/user.js"),
    passport = require("passport"),
    middleware = require("./middleware.js");

router.get('/register', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res)
{
    res.render("inregistrare");
});

router.post('/register', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res)
{
    User.register(new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        privileges: req.body.privileges
    }), req.body.password, function(err)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/register");
        }
        else
        {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
                res.redirect("/");
             });
        }
    })
});

router.get('/login', middleware.isLoggedOut, function(req, res)
{
    var title = "title"
    res.render("login", {title: title});
});

router.post("/login", middleware.isLoggedOut, passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/register",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}), function(req, res) {
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I'm registering a new user (if the DB is empty at that moment) everything is fine. If I try to register another user with the same region-id, I get this: 
[image: photo]

I tried using different region ids and the same fields for write, edit and read and it worked. I only get this when I have the same ids for region and I don't get why. Region is not declared as an index or with unique: true so why does it happen?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `region` used to be declared as `unique: true` which created a unique index on that field. Mongoose won't modify or remove existing indexes based on the schema, so you need to remove that obsolete index manually.

In the shell:

```
db.users.dropIndex('privileges.region_1')
```

Comment: Yeah. It was declared as unique:true because I wanted to make it unique for each user. (I mean, if privileges.region_0 = 1, any other privileges.region_i will not be 1 for the same user - but other users can have region = 1). I don't know if you get what I wanted to say, I tried my best to explain it. After that I saw that unique: true is another thing, not what I wanted and I modified it.